# Navigation drawer с ListView вместо меню

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Сделал кастомный Navigation drawer в активти с динамическим ListView  вместо меню.
Сам Navigation drawer работает нормально но все View(кнопки\чекбоксы и т.д.) на главном экране активти не откликаются на OnClickListener.
до этого все работало нормально и в других активити все работает нормально.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_fz_main" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_fz_main" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nwBackButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В активти через Butter Knife инициализация и с Navigation drawer никак больше не работаю

```
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

есть идеи где накосячить мог?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел как испоравить проблему)
просто добавить к леяутут в котором весь контент

```
 content.bringToFront();
```